# Npm link : cannot find library's module

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, npm-link

I work on a main app and an external library. 
I've used npm link to create a link in the main app to the library.

In the main app, I've added some imports like :

```
import { MyLibComponent} from '@scope/myLib';
```

Those imports used to work before I use the npm link (my lib is an azure artifact). But since I've created the symlinks with npm link I have compilations error like

> Cannot find module '@scope/myLib'.

In the main app angular.json I've already added "preserveSymlinks": true

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check whether the linked library is included in `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Yes after the npm link command I can see in node_modules/@scope/ that I do have a link leading to the library's root folder